# Expected private key to be an Uint8Array when deploying with hardhat

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I'm using OpenZeppelin's upgradeable contracts with its hardhat-ethers plugin and typechain plugin. However, I keep getting an error `Expected private key to be an Uint8Array` when I run the deployment.

Here's what I have for my deployment script:

```
import { providers } from "ethers";
import { ethers, upgrades } from "hardhat";

const provider = new providers.JsonRpcProvider();
const signer = provider.getSigner();

// Information about the signer does get logged out correctly
console.log(signer);

const factory = await ethers.getContractFactory('MyContract', signer)
await upgrades.deployProxy(factory);
```

When I console log the `signer`, it's information is logged out correctly, which I presume it means the signer information did get passed into the `getContractFactory`.

I'm running this in Jest. I'm not running this through `hardhat test` since this particular script isn't really a test but a deployment script that I plan to eventually use and I want to write a test for it. Unless the `hardhat test` has some magic injected when running, I don't see how different it would be when I run it like a regular nodejs script.

Why does it keep complaining that the private key needs to be an Uint8Array? I don't see how else I can pass any private key from the `signer` into the functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you directly use `ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider()`, it tries to connect to `localhost:8545`. Unless you are running `npx hardhat node`, it would give you an error.

Can you try using the provider from hardhat?

```
import { ethers, upgrades } from "hardhat";

const provider = ethers.provider; // using provider from hardhat
```

Also `private key needs to be an Uint8Array` is a weird error. Is it possible for you to include the error in your question?

Comment: If the JsonRpcProvider is connecting to localhost, by using the provider from hardhat, `ethers.provider`, where would it actually be connecting?

Comment: It generates an in-memory provider, more efficient, as it directly uses the EthereumJS APIs instead of exposing a JSON RPC server and serving requests from that.